# Can't get this simple Google Autocomplete script to work (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I have this at the bottom of a form partial, which worked previously when I loaded it through application.html.erb, but have since decided to replace it in application.html.erb with Google Maps.

_new.html.erb (with the field appropriately id'd).   straight up doesn't work, can't figure out why.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("autocomplete"));
    });

    function initAutocomplete(){
    }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCFm7OzAKuPbEa48b_aZ4S6JqMGVUCwwFs&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCFm7OzAKuPbEa48b_aZ4S6JqMGVUCwwFs&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

to the  in application.html.erb head tag

Then put

```
initAutocomplete = ->

$(document).ready ->
  autocomplete = new (google.maps.places.Autocomplete)(document.getElementById('autocomplete'))
  return
```

Into a coffeescript for you front page, or use your existing script inline of the partial to test if you need to.

Comment: Hi, thanks.   I'm kind of new and I'm not sure what an Inline Partial is, I'm going to research it.   The Rails partial and script that I want the autocomplete on loads inside a bootstrap modal.    The issue with application.html.erb is that I also want to have Google Maps running on the site, and you can only load one from there apparently.   So